# creating free and paid app for google play

Tags: android, google-play

I developed one application with advertisement. Now I am planning to make in paid without advertisement but free with advertisement.

Now my Question is: `Is it compulsory to make two version of app by changing package?`

if `NO` then how to manage the advertisement?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot publish two apps with the same package name on the Play Store.

You have two options here:

1. Remove ads and publish it as a separate app with a different package name
2. Make ad removal an in app purchase.

Comment: Thanks @Raghav Sood I know the first part but want to know regarding second part

Answer (score 2):

No, two applications / one app is not advised, if you want a free app and a paid version, the second version should be an in app purchase, when the buy has been registered you remove the ads.

Read up on in-app purchases and store a secure variable that remove the ads

Answer (score 1):

One app with in app purchase is the recommended way to go rather than two apps.

The android developer docs give details but you may want to look at this open source lib which handles the whole ad display/purchase logic for you.

https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary